# Does Sony RX10 camera support Sony SDK for remote control?

Tags: camera, sony

I have to developed a Windows application to remote control a camera from a pc for a photo booth. Basically this app will control zoom, exposure and shoot with a live view on the PC screen.

I'd like to use a Sony DSC RX10. Does this camera support Sony SDK ? If yes, are theses basic features supported by the SDK for the RX10 ?

Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

The RX10 does support the API although the documentation do not mention this camera. I own a RX10 and developed a Windows Phone app for this camera as Sony only provides an Android and an iPhone version. The RX10 supports the same functions as e.g. the RX100M (see the list of supported devices and functions on https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/).
Exposure control is not supported by the API, zoom, shoot and live view are OK.